# Ajax call inside class attribute

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm moving a php / js / ajax script to wordpress

I encountered something that i've never seen before, I understand what it does, but i'm trying to figure out how to make this work for wordpress.

the code:

```
<a id="a" class="tab block sel {content:'cont_1', ajaxContent:'php/templates.php',ajaxData:'type=pistols'}">Pistols</a>
<a id="b" class="tab block {content:'cont_2', ajaxContent:'php/templates.php',ajaxData:'type=rifles'}">Rifles</a>
<a id="c" class="tab block {content:'cont_3', ajaxContent:'php/templates.php',ajaxData:'type=shotguns'}">Shotguns</a>
<a id="d" class="tab block {content:'cont_4', ajaxContent:'php/templates.php',ajaxData:'type=cameras'}" >Cameras</a>
<a id="e" class="tab block {content:'cont_4', ajaxContent:'php/templates.php',ajaxData:'type=audios'}" >Audio</a>
```

Templates PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['type'])) {
    //The div for the manufacturer tabs, uniquely identified by the $_POST['type']
    echo "<ul id=\"".$_POST['type']."\" class=\"shadetabs\" style=\"position:relative; top:-12px; width:905px;\">";
    if ($_POST['type'] === 'pistols') {
        $manufacturers = .. and so on
```

From what i can understand, we are calling Templates.php and passing $_POST['type']. When this is compoleted, the script replaces the content of a `<div id="cont_1"`

in wordpress, i can't call random php files, since ajax will not work. I need to turn this into a function and hook it to wordpress.

Does anyone know how this type of code works?

As alternative, I'm planning to do the following, but I would prefer to keep it similar to the original code and this will need lots of extra lines of code.

```
var tab = jQuery("#a").type;
jQuery.ajax({
        url: custom_designer.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {
        action: 'php_template_function'
            type: tab
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById('caseclub_response').innerHTML = response;
            document.getElementById("buy_case_foam_added").submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried finding the original code using the Inspector?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how this type of code works?

It looks like there is some JavaScript that extracts the object string from the class attribute, then fetches the HTML from `template.php` and writes it somewhere.

For example:

```
function fetchList(element) {
  var settings = element.className.match(/\{.+\}/);
  settings = eval('(' + settings[0] + ')') // eww

  fetch(settings.ajaxContent, {
    method: 'post',
    body: settings.ajaxData
  }).then((response) => {
    // Error handling...
    response.text().then(() => {
      // Now writes the HTML somewhere...
    });
  });
}
```

If you want to copy what they did, see if you can find the original code using the Inspector.